# Change Bezier curve stroke

Tags: inkscape

I am new to graphic design and my information is very limited

After I have done the curve I noticed that it is not smooth curve

[image]

How can I change it to become smooth with same line width all over the line

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have some kind of path effect on the path. Try this: Select only the path by using the Edit Paths by Nodes Tool (F2). Click *Path > Remove Path Effect*

Comment: The solution in the above comment by Billy Kerr is more recommendable than the accepted answer, as it does not require redrawing.

Comment: @Moini I tried it, but it did not work !

Comment: Did you use the calligraphy tool to draw that line, then? I was assuming you used the Bézier tool in the wrong mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the displayed image, you may have selected the incorrect tool from the palette. If you pause over each tool, a tool tip will appear to display which one has been selected. It is going to be necessary to re-trace your curve rather than convert it, but you should find that easy enough to accomplish.

[image: inkscape bezier curve tool]

I made a brief attempt to trace your curve, without creating much smoothing. There's quite a bit of control with the handles of the curve tool:

[image: traced curve]

Comment: This is the tool i choose.. but when I increased the width of the line it became as in the image

Comment: Can you display or otherwise present the Stroke/Fill settings you are using?

Comment: I have put the image in the question

Comment: i had to rebuild the line. thanks